# Create variable dynamically from textbox

Tags: c#

I am trying to create some variables dynamically from a textbox or xml-script.
So far I am making a program to create scripts for the server application.
In that script I want to use variables which you can create in a form by entering a name and the type and maybe the scope.

So, if I enter *Counter* as an Int it has to create a variable called *Counter*.
Like: `int Counter = 0;`

Comment: You're going to need to define your question more.  How do you intend to use these variables? Are you compiling them into code? Are you trying to store them somewhere?

Comment: What is exactly the question ?

Answer (score 2):

Simple way would be to use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dynamicVars = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

You might have to wrap that in a class and add type checking for the objects in the dictionary, but the dictionary will give you the ability to create and add any type of name/value pair.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a variable based on input isn't a good idea, it's a huge amount of work and required a dynamic runtime. A much more simple approach is to use a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`, and use the text in the TextBox as a key.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<String,Type> dynamicVars = new Dictionary<String,Type>();

dynamicVars.Add("Counter",typeof(int));
```

The above code segment would do it. But I cannot fathom why you would need such a thing ?

Just Curious...

Comment: Well, i need a program where you can create your own scripts and add open database, select query's, open ftp en more of that stuff. So it makes it better and more flexible to work with it.